# cPanel Backup script moving wrong files

Tags: bash, backup, cpanel

I installed this backup script for cPanel which works fine (https://github.com/pietromalerba/cPanel-Full-Backup-Script).

I followed the template and created the folders `/backups/backup_daily` and `/backups/backup_monthly` and both cron jobs exactly as described by script.

The problem is that the **monthly backup file is being moved to the daily backup folder**.

And even though I manually move the monthly file to its folder, the next time I run the script it moves everything back to the daily folder.

I think the problem is at line 47 of **backup.sh**:

```
find $HOME -type f -name "backup-*" -exec mv {} $BACKUP_FOLDER/ \;
```

Would anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved changing line 47 to

```
find $HOME/* -maxdepth 0 -type f -name "backup-*" -exec mv {} $BACKUP_FOLDER/ \;
```